# Substituting environment variables in a file: awk or sed?

Tags: sed, awk, sh

I have a file of environment variables that I source in shell scripts, for example:

```
# This is a comment
ONE=1
TWO=2
THREE=THREE
# End
```

In my scripts, I source this file (assume it's called './vars') into the current environment, and change (some of) the variables based on user input. For example:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Read variables
source ./vars
# Change a variable
THREE=3
# Write variables back to the file??
awk 'BEGIN{FS="="}{print $1=$$1}' <./vars >./vars
```

As you can see, I've been experimenting with awk for writing the variables back, sed too. Without success. The last line of the script fails. Is there a way to do this with awk or sed (preferably preserving comments, even comments with the '=' character)? Or should I combine 'read' with string cutting in a while loop or some other magic? If possible, I'd like to avoid perl/python and just use the tools available in Busybox. Many thanks.

**Edit:** perhaps a use case might make clear what my problem is. I keep a configuration file consisting of shell environment variable declarations:

```
# File: network.config
NETWORK_TYPE=wired
NETWORK_ADDRESS_RESOLUTION=dhcp
NETWORK_ADDRESS=
NETWORK_ADDRESS_MASK=
```

I also have a script called 'setup-network.sh':

```
#!/bin/sh
# File: setup-network.sh

# Read configuration
source network.config

# Setup network
NETWORK_DEVICE=none
if [ "$NETWORK_TYPE" == "wired" ]; then
  NETWORK_DEVICE=eth0
fi
if [ "$NETWORK_TYPE" == "wireless" ]; then
  NETWORK_DEVICE=wlan0
fi
ifconfig -i $NETWORK_DEVICE ...etc
```

I also have a script called 'configure-network.sh':

```
#!/bin/sh
# File: configure-network.sh

# Read configuration
source network.config

echo "Enter the network connection type:"
echo "  1. Wired network"
echo "  2. Wireless network"
read -p "Type:" -n1 TYPE

if [ "$TYPE" == "1" ]; then
  # Update environment variable
  NETWORK_TYPE=wired
elif [ "$TYPE" == "2" ]; then
  # Update environment variable
  NETWORK_TYPE=wireless
fi

# Rewrite configuration file, substituting the updated value
# of NETWORK_TYPE (and any other updated variables already existing
# in the network.config file), so that later invocations of
# 'setup-network.sh' read the updated configuration.
# TODO
```

How do I rewrite the configuration file, updating only the variables already existing in the configuration file, preferably leaving comments and empty lines intact? Hope this clears things up a little. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use awk and read and write from the same file (is part of your problem).

I prefer to rename the file before I rewrite (but you can save to a tmp and then rename too).

```
/bin/mv file file.tmp
awk '.... code ...' file.tmp > file
```

If your env file gets bigger, you'll see that is is getting truncated at the buffer size of your OS.

Also, don't forget that gawk (the std on most Linux installations) has a built in array ENVIRON. You can create what you want from that

```
awk 'END {
   for (key in ENVIRON) {
      print key "=" ENVIRON[key]
   }
}' /dev/null
```

Of course you get everything in your environment, so maybe more than you want. But probably a better place to start with what you are trying to accomplish.

**Edit**
Most specifically

```
   awk -F"=" '{
     if ($1 in ENVIRON) {
         printf("%s=%s\n", $1, ENVIRON[$1])
     }
     # else line not printed or add code to meet your situation
   }' file > file.tmp
   /bin/mv file.tmp file
```

**Edit 2**
I think your var=values might need to be `export` -ed so they are visible to the awk ENVIRON array.

AND

```
echo PATH=xxx| awk -F= '{print ENVIRON[$1]}'
```

prints the existing value of PATH.

I hope this helps.

P.S. as you appear to be a new user, if you get an answer that helps you please remember to mark it as accepted, and/or give it a + (or -) as a useful answer.

Comment: Thanks for having a shot, but again I don't think I've made myself clear. Is there a sh/sed/awk equivalent of: perl -ne '/^([^=]+)/; print "$1=$ENV{$1}\n";'?

Comment: Thanks again. Your edit seems to be more like what I'm after, however the ENVIRON[$1] statement doesn't expand properly. Are you able to double-check that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know what you are trying to do, but if you are trying to change the value of variable THREE ,

```
awk -F"=" -vt="$THREE" '$1=="THREE" {$2=t}{print $0>FILENAME}' OFS="=" vars
```

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer. I want to read variables from a file into the environment (the file is snippet #1). Then I want to update one or two of the variables in the environment (updating THREE is only an example, it could be any of the variables), then rewrite the file with updated values. So: read, change, write. The trick is only writing back variables that were in the file in the first place (not the whole environment). And preserving comments in the original file would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in just with bash:

```
rewrite_config() {
    local filename="$1"
    local tmp=$(mktemp)

    # if you want the header
    echo "# File: $filename" >> "$tmp"

    while IFS='=' read var value; do
        declare -p $var | cut -d ' ' -f 3-
    done < "$filename" >> "$tmp"

    mv "$tmp" "$filename"
}
```

Use it like

```
source network.config
# manipulate the variables
rewrite_config network.config
```

I use a temp file to maintain the existance of the config file for as long as possible.

Comment: Thanks Glenn, this is a good solution. I hadn't thought of using declare. Note that including the header (as in your example) clobbers subsequent calls to rewrite_config, but otherwise it's good.

Comment: I was bouncing around with various `eval` solutions until I read about `declare`.